# How to resolve the error "Unable to validate properties of null value"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to implement user authentication via phone number using Firebase.

The FirebasePhoneAuth component represents a form with an input field for the phone number and a "Send Verification Code" button.
When the "Send Verification Code" button is pressed, the sendVerificationCode function is called, which sends a request to the Firebase server to send an SMS with the confirmation code to the entered phone number.
After a successful request, the result will be the creation of a confirmationResult object, which stores information about the phone number and the confirmation code.

Question: When pressing the "SEND CODE" button, an error alert "cannot read property verify of undefined" occurs. How can I solve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence,signInWithPhoneNumber,getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyD5Qg_t9KR4TmLr2p14E2aODO9UV5RehUE",
  authDomain: "sharq-9ec25.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://sharq-9ec25-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "sharq-9ec25",
  storageBucket: "sharq-9ec25.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "613514564466",
  appId: "1:613514564466:web:c76f60d1a5d151689e83eb",
  measurementId: "G-BGWW40HYBJ"
};
// initialize Firebase App
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// initialize Firebase Auth for that app immediately
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});

const FirebasePhoneAuth = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(""); //  для номера телефона
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState(""); //  для кода подтверждения
  const [confirmationResult, setConfirmationResult] = useState(null); //  для результатов

const sendVerificationCode = async () => {
  try {
    const confirmation = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber);
    setConfirmationResult(confirmation);
  } catch (err) {
    Alert.alert("Error", err.message);
  }  
};
  const confirmVerificationCode = async () => {
    try {
      if (confirmationResult) {
        await confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode);
        Alert.alert("Успех", "Номер телефона успешно подтвержден");
  
    // Сохранение номера телефона в AsyncStorage
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
  } else {
    Alert.alert("Ошибка", "Не удалось подтвердить номер телефона");
  }
  } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Ошибка", error.message);
    }
  };

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Введите номер телефона"
        onChangeText={(value) => setPhoneNumber(value)}
      />
      <Button onPress={sendVerificationCode} title="Отправить код подтверждения" />

  {confirmationResult && (
    <>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Введите код подтверждения"
        onChangeText={(value) => setVerificationCode(value)}
      />
      <Button onPress={confirmVerificationCode} title="Подтвердить код подтверждения" />
    </>
  )}
</View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    width: "80%",
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default FirebasePhoneAuth;
```